# how to use ember.js to create a google map from .json

Tags: ember.js

First of all I am new to ember.js and I just finished the tutorial on the website and I am confident I can use it to create what i want.

I have a xy.json with an Array of Objects.
These Objects contain: latitude, longitude and some more information.
Now every object in the .json shall have marker on a google map, and a navigation that centers the view on the map and creates an url to the right view.

---

I believe I need two handlebar templates (application and index). 
Application for the Navigation, and Index for the map.

Now I need to put the Data (.json) into a module and loop over it.

```
For objects in Objects 
    ....
end
```

But i am not sure how i will be able to create links to center google maps and put the markers on the map.

Appreciate any help to get me kickstarted in the right direction. >_<
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating an Ember `Component` that implements the map.  To configure and add markers to the map, you would implement `didInsertElement` in the `Component`.  If you do this:

```
App.GoogleMapComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var map = Ember.$(this.get('element'));
        // ... configure map ...
    }
});
```

Then in your template, you can use:

```
{{#each loc in model}}
    {{google-map location=loc}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: A Component is a handlebar template where i (like i would normally do) place the map? The Javascript needed for the map i can safely place in the head? 

How can i save my JSON inside a variable, or is it better to transform my JSON into an Object? The structure is as follows:
`{{#each model}} <li class="list-group-item"> <h2>{{place_name}}</h2> {{#each programme_entries}} <hr> <h4>{{title}}<span class="badge pull-right">{{from_to}}</span></h4> <p>{{description}}</p> <p>{{details}}</p> <p>Tags: {{kind}}</p> </hr> {{/each}} {{/each}}`

Comment: A lot of questions in your comment!  A `Component` may or may not have a template, it is not required.  The naming convention I have shown will work (`{{google-map}}` implies `GoogleMapComponent`).  As far as your other questions, I'd recommend brushing up on sections of the guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/  Your other questions should be covered there.

Comment: Yeah, i was reading through A LOT of stuff, but since i am also quite unfamiliar with javascript, everything is still a little massy in my head.

I thought that i read somewhere That "GoogleMapComponent" is more like a naming convention, and doesnt have to do anything with functionality. I understand that when when i define my map with markers i can look through the component and query the information for the navbar..(?) but: first of all i need a basic map (how can i load the api?) and second of all i will need the data from the json (how can i parse it into an usable marker) :D Thank You!

Comment: I found this earlier, 

and was wondering why it uses views instead of components, and why i cant add google maps like in the example – grunt/bower seems to remove any sources that arent in the gruntfile :(

Anyway, thanks for the link i will try studying it a little and see what i can come up with. Ember seems to have a really steep learning curve and i am missing some guidance, the guide has lot's of information but i am missing some explanations to all the  facts... (;